# How to use external libraries with CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

My project structure looks like this, and I want to derive my classes using libraries on ***ext*** to ***inc*** folder and use them on *main.cpp*. What should the skeleton of *CMakeLists.txt* look like?

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── ext
│   ├── abseil-cpp
│   └── SDL2-2.0.9
├── inc
├── src
└── main.cpp
```

Comment: Are the `ext` already compiled?

Comment: Nope... I don't know, should compile them? Isn't let CMake to know `include` folders inside libraries in `ext` enough?

Comment: Definitely not if these libraries need to be compiled! They need to be configured, built, installed.

Comment: Gosh... Didn't know that... Got it!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build the libraries as part of the project, yes, that will work as long as the external libraries are Cmake based and you modify their Cmake files appropriately for your project.

However, CMake has a module called [`ExternalProject`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) designed to help you manage third party dependencies. You can find a pretty thorough write up on it [at this website](https://www.selectiveintellect.net/blog/2016/7/29/using-cmake-to-add-third-party-libraries-to-your-project-1). `ExternalProject` contains everything you need to create a custom target to drive download, update/patch, configure, build, install and test steps of an external project.

There are other options as well, I prefer using pre-built libraries to cut down on build times. (CI services cost less when it takes less time to run) So I've grown fond of [Conan](https://conan.io), an open source, decentralized and multi-platform
package manager most often used for C++. It also has great [Cmake integration](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/integrations/cmake.html) so it fits perfectly into my workflow.